# TypeError: invalid rect assignment, what's wrong?

Tags: python, pygame

I try to build a game with sprite of spaceship but when i run the code, i get a error - `TypeError: invalid rect assignment`. I don't understard what i do wrong. help me please.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
size = (600, 600)
Spaceship_position = [260, 510]

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Spaceships")
icon = pygame.image.load("D:\\Yahav\\Cyber\\Cyber_Images\\icon.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()


class Spaceship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("D:\\Yahav\\Cyber\\Cyber_Images\\spaceship.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = (100, 100)


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
spaceship = Spaceship()
all_sprites.add(spaceship)


def main():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
        all_sprites.update()
        all_sprites.draw(screen)


main()
```

what i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the line

> ```py
> self.rect.bottom = (100, 100)
> ```

`rect.bottom` is the bottom of the rectangle. Hence you have assign a single value to the virtual attribute `rect.bottom`:

```py
self.rect.bottom = 100
```

If you want to set the bottom left corner, then you have to assign a tuple:

```py
self.rect.bottomleft = (100, 100)
```

See [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html):

> The Rect object has several virtual attributes which can be used to move and align the Rect:
>
> ```py
> x,y
> top, left, bottom, right
> topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
> midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
> center, centerx, centery
> size, width, height
> w,h
> ```
>
> All of these attributes can be assigned to:
>
> ```py
> rect1.right = 10
> rect2.center = (20,30)
> ```